# How to make Navbar change from transparent to solid on screen resize (not scroll)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need help making my Navbar change from transparent to solid when I resize the screen (as on a smartphone), but I want it to stick to the top of the page and won't go down as I scroll. I added the "bg-dark" class but then it won't be transparent anymore. Here is the code:

```css
#main {
  position: relative;
  background: url('https://images.template.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/15125202/Beautiful-Travel-Photography.jpg?width=600');
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 220px 0 200px;
}

#header {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-brand {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.nav-item {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
  background: #bbbbbb;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
  margin-top: 7px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 0.9;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.navbar-brand:hover {
  color: grey;
}

.fa {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.fa-facebook {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
    <title>Landing Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Landing Page</a>
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
            aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#"
                  >Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link px-2" href="#"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="main">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5 text-white">
            <h1>Landing Page</h1>
            <h3>
              Welcome to my website
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $("#myCarousel").carousel();
      });
    </script>
</body>
```

I'm looking for something like this website: http://electricblaze.com/unicore/index7.html

Comment: do you want the navbar transparent on large (ie: desktop) or mobile? also the example you referenced changes on scroll (no on resize) so it's make it hard to understand what you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

In your CSS you would include something like this.

```
@media (min-width: 800px) {
    .nav {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this

in your js file

```
var navbar = document.querySelector('.you navbar class');

window.addEventListener(scroll,handleScroll );

function handleScroll()  {
        if (window.pageYOffset >= 45) {
           navbar.classList.add('scrolled);
        }
        else {

           navbar.classList.remove('scrolled);
        }
    }
```

scrolled class in css file

```
.scrolled{
  background:#202020;
}
```

Comment: it's on scroll not resize use media queries